# Assembly Get parameter after call _fun

Tags: assembly, masm

I want to do something like this:

```
    call _function
    dd 5.91
```

Is it possible to get 5.91 as a parameter of _function?

Comment: Um, 5.91 is a floating point number, but `dd` is for 32-bit integers. Even after you fix that, you don't want to do it because it will mess up the return address predictor.

Comment: @RaymondChen actually `dd` is for 32 bit whatever, so it works for a 32 bit float fine.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected. But I still would not recommend this because it causes your returns to be mispredicted, which will incur a significant runtime penalty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it is. Since the return address placed on the stack points at that dword, you can reference it using `[esp]` (as long as you haven't changed `esp` of course). You will also want to adjust the return address so that when the function exits it does not try to execute that argument as code. In most cases, this is not recommended.